# Docker RUN Not Finding an Executable File

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am having issues setting up a `Dockerfile` in Ubuntu. I tried the following command:

```
sudo docker build -t chaste .
```

But when it reaches to the following command:

```
RUN chmod +x chaste.sh && ./chaste.sh -q && rm -f chaste.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
chmod: cannot access 'chaste.sh': No such file or directory
```

However, `chaste.sh` is in the current directory. I am not sure why it complains about not being able to find it.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Comment: can you show directory structure? and the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

To use the file from current directory you should add it from build context to the container by adding the following command above `RUN` command in your Dockerfile:

```
ADD ./chaste.sh ./chaste.sh
```

Comment: You should usually prefer `COPY` to `ADD`, unless you specifically want `ADD`'s more unusual features (fetching remote URLs, unpacking tar files).